# Restrict a record to be claimed once in the database

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

Consider the following tables:

table: `rates`
columns: `id`, `label`

table: `business_rates`
columns: `id`, `rate_id`, `business_id`

table: `assignment_rates`
columns: `id`, `rate_id`, `assignment_id`

The business rule is that the record from `rates` can be claimed ONCE by either `business_rates` or `assignment_rates`.

For example, there is a record in `rates` with an `id` of `100`. It is claimed by `business_rates` (eg: `{id:1, business_id:1, rate_id:100}`). If someone attempts to add `rate_id=100` in `assignment_rates`, it should raise an exception at the database layer.

Is this even possible to do this at the database layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create triggers for both `business_rates` and `assignment_rates` tables. 
The trigger for `assignment_rates` may look like this:

```
create or replace function assignment_rates_trigger()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    if exists (
        select 1 
        from business_rates 
        where rate_id = new.rate_id)
    then
        raise exception 'Rate % exists in business_rates.', new.rate_id;
    end if;
    return new;
end $$;

create trigger assignment_rates_trigger
before insert or update on assignment_rates
for each row execute procedure assignment_rates_trigger();

insert into assignment_rates values (1, 100, 1);

ERROR:  Rate 100 exists in business_rates.
```

The trigger for `business_rates` should look analogously.

Read also: [Trigger Procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) and [CREATE TRIGGER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html).

Comment: Thanks, that totally worked. Appreciate the prompt response!